# Short and long versions of cref

Tags: cleveref

Is there a way to have a short and long version of `\cref` just like there is a capital and small version of it? I want to use the long version (Like Figure 1) in most of my document. But in some tikz figures, I want to add the references in short format (Like Fig.1) to save space.

Obligatory MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\Crefname{lemma}{Lemma}{Lemmas}
\Crefname{theorem}{Theorem}{Theorem}
\Crefname{figure}{Figure}{Figures}
% Short refs
% \crefname{lemma}{Lem.}{Lems.}
% \crefname{theorem}{Thm.}{Thms.}
% \crefname{figure}{Fig.}{Figs.}

\def\shortcref#1{\cref{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \caption{Test}
  \label{fig:myfig}
\end{figure}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm:my}
  My result
\end{theorem}
\begin{lemma}\label{lem:my}
  My Lemma
\end{lemma}

This is my long format \Cref{fig:myfig}, \Cref{thm:my} and \Cref{lem:my}.

This is my short format \shortcref{fig:myfig}, \shortcref{thm:my} and \shortcref{lem:my}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that `cleveref` manages abbreviations is to set them at initial load time, so there's no built-in way to manage this. But, `\crefname` defines its effects locally, so

```
{\crefname{figure}{fig.}{figs.}\cref{foo}} \cref{foo}
```

would give output of

> fig. 3 figure 3

So we can do something like this to get your desired result:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\CrefAbbrevNames}{}
  {%
    \crefname{figure}{fig.}{figs.}%
    \crefname{theorem}{thm.}{thms.}%
    etc.
  }
\NewDocumentCommand{\shortcref}{ s m }
  {{% ❶
    \CrefAbbrevNames
    \cref
      \IfBooleanT{#1}{*}% ❷
      {#2}%
  }}
```

Note the use of an extra set of braces ❶ so that the redefinitions will appear in a group. Also, since `\cref` potentially takes a `*`-form (for use with `hyperref` to suppress hyperlink), I've added a check for a `*` after `\shortcref` to add it into the call to `\cref`. ❷

The definition for `\CrefAbbrevNames` would be more complicated for a polyglot document.

I had originally contemplated making the `\cref*` equivalent to `\shortcref` until I remembered the potential `*`-form that already existed.